# Generate random long number

Tags: c++

I know that to generate random long number, I do following steps in Java:

```
Random r = new Random();
return r.nextLong();
```

What will be equivalent of this code in C++? like this?

```
return (long)rand();
```

Comment: "we know that to generate random long number we do following steps" Do you? In which language?

Comment: @sbi: The code snippet is for Java (as any seasoned Java programmer can tell you), however, yes, you rightly point out that the OP could have stated this more directly.

Comment: Looks like Java or C# - too late :)

Comment: no you can't do `return (long) rand();`

Answer (score 14):

`<cstdlib>` provides int rand().  You might want to check out the man page.  If long is bigger than int on your system, you can call rand() twice and put the first value in the high word.

```
#include <cstdlib>

long lrand()
{
    if (sizeof(int) < sizeof(long))
        return (static_cast<long>(rand()) << (sizeof(int) * 8)) |
               rand();

    return rand();
}
```

(it's very unlikely that long is neither the same as or double the size of int, so this is practical if not theoretically perfect)

Check your docs for rand() though.  It's not a great generator, but good enough for most things.  You'll want to call srand() to initialise the random-number generation system.  Others have commented that Windows doesn't return sizeof(int) randomised bits, so you may need to tweak the above.

Comment: I think the `static_cast<long>` should only contain the first `rand()`, right? The current version bitshifts an `int` by `sizeof(int)*8`, which is basically an "identify function", i.e., you get just the same value again.

Comment: @bluenote10: well spotted... will fix.  Cheers.

Comment: A Java long is always 64bit.
As long on most systems is only 32bit in C++, I would rather use a function long long llrand() instead.

Answer (score 10):

Using [boost random library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) can save you of quite nasty surprises with (pseudo)random numbers

Comment: "Use boost to solve <*> problem" became a standard answer on any type of question :P.

Comment: @virious: I don't know of "any question". Here it's all about an algorithm. Sure, you can code your own version of Mersenne Twister, or summon hard-to-find bugs by hacking the standard rand() --- or use boost::random, which is, like, three lines of code.

Comment: it was just my feeling, in general, not in case of your particular answer :). Yes, it's obvious that boost is a very well optimized set of libraries which is used very often.

Comment: Same as "use jQuery" answers for Javascript :)

Comment: @LukaRamishvili Knowing close to nothing about jQuery, I still am going to contest your comment. Various ``hacks'' of random generators are known to lead to very bad quality randomness of a resulting generator.

Comment: @Zhenya It's just that such answers are common, not that they are wrong. Lots of questions are asked about how to do it in plain Javascript when using jQuery would be better, even good for learning.

Comment: And on another question I guess, I found a comment I couldn't agree more, and that was basically what you're saying - that many nasty problems and bugs are only later discovered to be caused by some underlying RNG hack instead of using a well-tested library.

Answer (score 6):

First, you have ton know that in the current standard C++ there is no random library. In fact there is one, but it's available in a sperate namespace called TR1 because it's the result of a Technical Report done in 2003. It will be available in the standard library for the next standard (coming next year if all goes well).

So if you have a recent compiler (VS2008 or lasts versions of GCC) you have access to the std::tr1::random library; If you have a compiler implementing the parts of the next standard, then you have it std::random.

If you don't have access to that library, there is an implementation available in the boost libraries : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

Now in all cases, the way to get a random number is the same as it's all the same library (from the boost doc):

```
boost::mt19937 rng;                 // produces randomness out of thin air
                                    // see pseudo-random number generators
boost::uniform_int<> six(1,6);      // distribution that maps to 1..6
                                    // see random number distributions
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> >
         die(rng, six);             // glues randomness with mapping
int x = die();                      // simulate rolling a die
```

Comment: Wouldn't `using namespace boost::random;` put all of `boost::random` into the _current_ namespace? How then would the compiler find it in `boost`? What am I missing?

Comment: @sbi: using makes it available in both.
@Klaim: what about cstdlib?

Comment: @Tony: I don't see how this is supposed to happen. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @sbi: say you #include <string> / using namespace std; - afterwards string and std::string can both be used interchangeably... they refer to the same thing.  using grants a kind of liberty to the compiler to look somewhere extra implicitly, but it doesn't move things from their original namespace.  Is that clearer?

Comment: @Tony: Well, [I do know a few basics of C++](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/49/c?userid=140719). `<wry_smile>` However, I still fail to see how using namespace boost::random; (as was in the original version of Klaim's answer) puts everything from boost::random into boost (unless the using directive is put into boost, of course, which it wasn't).

Comment: I added first using boost::random to the example, thinking there was a missing line in the example of the doc. But it's not a mistake, so I fixed it. See the first page of the doc.

Answer (score 4):

C++11 provides the [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) library. To generate a `long`, you would use code like:

```
#include <random>
#include <climits>

...

std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<long> distribution(LONG_MIN,LONG_MAX);
long result = distribution(generator);
```

Answer (score 3):

Portable hack:

```
long r = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(long)/sizeof(int); i++)
{
    r = r << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BITS);
    r |= rand();
}
return r;
```

Why do you need a random long anyway?

Comment: It is not a good idea in Visual Studio, RAND_MAX is 2^15-1 and many bits will be 0 in the final number.

Comment: To be perfectly portable, always use `CHAR_BITS`, instead of the literal `8`.

Comment: Are you sure of the quality of random numbers you're getting this way?

Comment: There aren't any systems today where CHAR_BITS is not 8, but sure. And the quality of random numbers from rand() isn't very good anyway. If one makes sure to avoid those 0 bits portably, we'd need floor(log_2(RAND_MAX)) and only use that many bits of the return value. Depending on the requirements, this might be a little overkill.

Comment: Doing Monte Carlo similations for a sizable fraction of my work time, I've seen quite a few disasters where the problem was really due to a bad random number generator or a "simple" hack of it. Frankly, I'd say that what you're suggesting is a step too close to a big no-no.

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I use. It is returning numbers in range [0, 2^64-1].

```
unsigned long long unsignedLongLongRand()
{
    unsigned long long rand1 = abs(rand());
    unsigned long long rand2 = abs(rand());
    rand1 = rand1 << (sizeof(int)*8);   
    unsigned long long randULL = (rand1 | rand2);   
    return randULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this function works like rand() and uses Unsigned Long Type:

```
unsigned long _LongRand ()
{

unsigned char MyBytes[4];
unsigned long MyNumber = 0;
unsigned char * ptr = (unsigned char *) &MyNumber;

MyBytes[0] = rand() % 256; //0-255
MyBytes[1] = rand() % 256; //256 - 65535
MyBytes[2] = rand() % 256; //65535 -
MyBytes[3] = rand() % 256; //16777216

memcpy (ptr+0, &MyBytes[0], 1);
memcpy (ptr+1, &MyBytes[1], 1);
memcpy (ptr+2, &MyBytes[2], 1);
memcpy (ptr+3, &MyBytes[3], 1);

return(MyNumber);
}
```